# Delete a pod from kubernetes v1.25.6

Tags: kubernetes

What is the proper way to delete pod running on kubernetes v1.25.6?
I tried `kubectl delete pod microservie-one-549464c5bb-7dtjq` but the pod is automatically created again.

Comment: The pod is related to a deployment named `microservie-one`. Whenever you delete a pod from this deployment, it will be created again. If you do not want any pods from this deployment, you should delete the deployment.

Comment: how I can delete the deployment?

Comment: `kubectl delete deployment microservie-one`

Answer (score 1):

The proper way is to delete the `deploy` that creates the `pod`

List the deploys use:

```
kubectl [-n namespace] get deploy
```

and assuming your deploy is named: `microservie-one`

```
kubectl [-n namespace] delete deploy microservie-one
```

---

To recreate the pod anew, you will need to reapply the manifest:

```
kubectl [-n namespace] apply -f microservie-one.yaml
```

---

Anoter way to stop a pod, without destroying the deployment is to scale down the deployment to `0` replicas, and when you need it to scale it up to `1` replica:

```bash
kubectl [-n namespace] scale deployment/microservie-one --replicas=0
#later
kubectl [-n namespace] scale deployment/microservie-one --replicas=1
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete a Pod running on Kubernetes, you can use the kubectl delete command followed by the Pod name or a label selector. Here's an example:

```
kubectl delete pod <pod-name>
```

Alternatively, you can use a label selector to delete multiple Pods at once:

```
kubectl delete pods -l <label-selector>
```

If you want to force delete the Pod without waiting for it to gracefully terminate, you can add the --force and --grace-period=0 flags:

```
kubectl delete pod <pod-name> --force --grace-period=0
```

This will immediately delete the Pod without giving it a chance to terminate gracefully.

You can also delete all the Pods in a particular namespace using the following command:

```
kubectl delete pods --all -n <namespace>
```

Note that deleting a Pod will cause Kubernetes to create a new one to maintain the desired state of the system.

Remember to also delete the deployment so the pod doesn't get created again

```
kubectl delete deployment microservie-one-549464c5bb-7dtjq
```